# How to escape comma on mount options for overlay

Tags: mount, overlayfs

To mount overlay it is given `lowerdir`, `upperdir` and `workdir` as options on [mount(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) or data on [mount(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mount), what logic is applied in order to escape commas? I have tried double commas and even quoting with no success.

There is two workaround I found that is not exactly what I want:

1. Relative path: as far as the last component doesn't have commas the following works:

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/a,b /tmp/a,b/{upper,lower,work,merged}
   cd /tmp/a,b
   sudo mount \
     -t overlay \
     -o 'lowerdir=./lower,upperdir=./upper,workdir=./work' \
     overlay \
     '/tmp/a,b/merged'
   ```

   But I reinforce that it doesn't work if the last component contains commas.
2. Move path after mounting: I believe kernel keep the `inode` track, as the option values on `/proc/self/mountinfo` doesn't change:

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/a\ b /tmp/a\ b/{upper,lower,work,merged}
   sudo mount \
     -t overlay \
     -o 'lowerdir=/tmp/a b/lower,upperdir=/tmp/a b/upper,workdir=/tmp/a b/work' \
     overlay \
     '/tmp/a b/merged'
   mv '/tmp/a b' '/tmp/a,b'
   fgrep merged /proc/self/mountinfo
   314 86 0:56 / /tmp/a,b/merged rw,relatime shared:217 - overlay overlay rw,lowerdir=/tmp/a\040b/lower,upperdir=/tmp/a\040b/upper,workdir=/tmp/a\040b/work
   ```

**Note**:
As kernel escapes space, tab, new lines and backslash characters with three decimal digits I have also tried to escape comma with `\044` with no success, it seems it wants to escape backslash again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslash will escape it. Since the mount command sends it as-is (as can be seen with *strace*), this has to be the kernel which uses a backslash to escape it.

```
mount -t overlay \
  -o 'lowerdir=/tmp/a\,b/lower,upperdir=/tmp/a\,b/upper,workdir=/tmp/a\,b/work' \
  overlay '/tmp/a,b/merged'
```

I think the kernel's escapes in octal seen in `/proc/mounts` is to help parsers: a `,` will always be a separator. Then it's up to the parser to finaly resolve `\134\054` into `\,` then `,` as part of a path or filename.

This is a part of the overlayfs handling of options in kernel, in [`linux/fs/overlayfs/super.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/fs/overlayfs/super.c#L425):

> ```
> static char *ovl_next_opt(char **s)
> {
>   char *sbegin = *s;
>   char *p;
>
>   if (sbegin == NULL)
>       return NULL;
>
>   for (p = sbegin; *p; p++) {
>       if (*p == '\\') {
>           p++;
>           if (!*p)
>               break;
>       } else if (*p == ',') {
>           *p = '\0';
>           *s = p + 1;
>           return sbegin;
>       }
>   }
>   *s = NULL;
>   return sbegin;
> }
> ```

where the backslash can be seen to escape the character next to it (thus avoiding the specific handling of the comma that would have happened below).

Comment: I see `,` is hexa `2c` so decimal `44` but octal `054`, in that case I found that if one have backslash it should be doubled as well, e.g.: with `'/tmp/a,b\c'`:  
`313 86 0:55 / /tmp/a,b\134c/merged rw,relatime shared:217 - overlay overlay rw,lowerdir=/tmp/a\134\054b\134\134c/lower,upperdir=/tmp/a\134\054b\134\134c/upper,workdir=/tmp/a\134\054b\134\134c/work`